# Is $``A$ because of $B"$ false if $B$ is false?

Tags: logic

I need to find the truth value of the statement $``A$ because of $B"$, and all we know is that $B$ is false. My guess is that the statement is false, because the reason you provided is false. For examples, $``0 = 0$ because $0 = 1"$ is considered false (Okay, provided that we are not in the zero ring...) Am I right?

EDIT-1: Answering anomaly's question: I think my interpretation of $``A$ because of $B"$ is $``$the reason $A$ holds is $B$ holds$"$.

Comment: I would say it's vacuously true.  I interpret "$A$ because of $B$" as "If $B$ then $A$" from a logic standpoint.  But I'm not an expert.

Comment: What does "because of" mean?

Comment: @anomaly That's exactly what I want to know, i.e. how to translate "because of" in natural language to proposition. Perhaps we are not even allow to do so?

Comment: "Because" in English has a great deal of ambiguity.  "$A$ because $B$" can mean that $B$ causes $A$, and then there are various senses of "cause" (I won't elaborate if not needed).  Sometimes it means that $B$ logically implies $A$, or that there's a valid argument with $B$ as premise and $A$ as conclusion.  There are weaker logical relations that might be intended.  For example, maybe it means that if it were the case that $B$, it would be the case that $A$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Possible_world_semantics).  There are probably other senses.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by 'because of'.  If you interpret it as 'follows from', then '$A$ because of $B$' becomes '$A$ follows from $B$', i.e. 'whenever $B$ is true, $A$ will be true'.

Now, if we would know that $B$ is *always* false, then 'whenever $B$ is true, $A$ will be true' will be vacuously true as well: In all zero cases where $B$ is true, $A$ will indeed be true.

But if we merely know that $B$ is false, we can't say much about 'whenever $B$ is true, $A$ will be true'.  For example, it could be that $B$ is a contingent statement, and hence there is a possible world where it is True. As such, we can't say anything about 'whenever $B$ is true, $A$ will be true' unless we know something more about $A$, and of course how it relates to $B$, but the bottom line is in that case we cannot say whether '$A$ follows from $B$' is true of false.

In neither case, though, can we say that '$A$ follows from $B$' merely on the basis of $B$ being false.

Comment: I think "if we know that B is _always_ true" was a typo for "if we know that B is _always_ false".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Whoops! Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "because of" has no standard mathematical meaning.  As a result, there is no standard way to translate "$A$ because of $B$" into formal logic and it has no well-defined truth value, unless some such definition has been provided in the context in which you are working.